# why do I have to write Sudo every time in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, frontend, sudo

I'm creating a react app, using command
`create react-app new-app`
but it's not creating a new app until i change this command to
`sudo create react-app new-app`.

After this if I try to install any dependency using npm then also I have to include sudo in the beginning of every command.
And also sometimes the project files are not accessible by code editor as they get locked .

please help me to get rid of this sudo ...

Comment: Seems like the ownership of the directory and files is not yours but to `root`. You should probably change that with `chown <username>:<username> -R` executed where your project is.

Comment: Also, consider [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [unix.se] for more help with Linux and Unix stuff.

Comment: chown solved the problem.... Thanks a lot............

Comment: Why are you not using `npx create-react-app my-app` as [documented](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview)?

Answer (score 1):

Sudo used to stand for *"Superuser do"* It simply means that your operating system thinks that you don't own the directory. You can use this command to resolve the issue: `chown [username]:[username] -R`. chown is short for *"Change Owner"*.

Here's a trick you could use in the future - incase you have to execute the previous command using `sudo` you can punch in `sudo !!` and this will run the previous command as `root`.

So how that would work is:

1. `some command` - Doesn't run and you need sudo.
2. `sudo !!` - executes `sudo some command` automatically.

Best wishes :)

Comment: "*Sudo stands for "Superuser do"*" not quite. Or not any more. Take your pick. It originally stood for that but it could only run stuff as the super user. For a long time now, `sudo` can be used to run commands as *any* user, e.g. `sudo -u otherUser` will run the next command using the `otherUser` account on the computer. So, nowadays some have changed the acronym to "*substitute* user do" but I personally just prefer to not assign any phrases - `sudo` runs a command as a different user, often "root".

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of specifying "sudo" everytime using `sudo -s` command.
If no command is specified after passing de "-s" argument to "sudo", an interactive shell is executed, you will not need to specify sudo again in this session.